# comparing dataset through vb.net

Tags: file-io, dataset, vb.net-2010

dasaset (ds) contain value like this comapring two dataset and write the phone number from dataset to notepad which is not equal to dataset1.but am getting the result in notepad like the phone numbers which are equal to both dataset

```
dataset
-------
91  9942321400
91  9865015695
91  9677031515
91  9994828285
91  9688104229

dataset1 values
----------------
91  9942321400
91  9865015695
91  9677031515

expected result in notepad
--------------------------
91  9994828285
91  9688104229

my code
-------
Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim toggle As Boolean = False
        Do While (i <= ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
            Dim phone As String = ds1.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString
            Dim j As Integer = 0
            Do While (j <= Ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
                Dim dumphone As String = Ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item(4).ToString
                If dumphone <> phone Then toggle = True 'This will set your flag to add the output.
                j = (j + 1)
            Loop
            'After we're done checking if there's a match, we decided to add it to the output.
            If toggle = True Then

                TextBox1.AppendText(a.ToString & "|" & b.ToString & "|" & c.ToString & "|" & d.ToString & "|" & phone.ToString & "|" & e1.ToString & "|" & f.ToString & "|" & g.ToString & "|" & h.ToString & "|" & i1.ToString & "|" & j1.ToString & "|" & k.ToString & "|" & l.ToString & "|" & m.ToString & "|" & n1.ToString & "|" & o.ToString & "|" & p.ToString & "|" & q.ToString & "|" & r.ToString & "|" & s.ToString & "|" & t.ToString & "|" & u.ToString & "|" & v.ToString & "|" & w.ToString & "|" & x.ToString)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
                TextBox1.Text = ""
                toggle = False 'Reset the flag for the next value
            End If
            i = (i + 1) 'Move to the next value to check against.
        Loop



but am getting the output in note pad like this
------------------------------------------------
91  9942321400
91  9865015695
91  9677031515
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this way and I got the result you were looking for...

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            Dim found As Boolean = False
            For j As Integer = 0 To dataset1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                If dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString = dataset1.Tables(0).Rows(j)    (0).ToString Then
                    found = True
                End If
            Next
            If found = False Then
                'here you are getting the right result in each loop
                'in this example i'm showing the result in a textbox
                'just change the instruction and write them in your note pad or wherever you want to
                MsgBox(dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString)
            End If
        Next
```